# find_by_sql in ruby on rails gives an error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to get the value of a column in ruby on rails i use find_by_sql to get the value in mysql-cmd the value returns correctly but in view page it returns a random value

```
passed_question = params[:passed_question]
@answer.questions_id = passed_question
next_question = params[:next_question]
@question = Question.find_by_id(passed_question)
@module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]
```

it **127450632** value 
but in mysql cmd

```
mysql> select student_additional_field_id from questions
-> where id=3;
+-----------------------------+
| student_additional_field_id |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `find_by_sql` will return an Array

How are you trying to access the value from result ?

have you tried it like this

```
@module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]

student_additional_field_id = @module[0].student_additional_field_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
@module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]
```

Should probably be:

```
@module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE ?", passed_question]
```

UPDATE:

It would have been nice if I had posted [a link to the doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) and more explanation. When using variable in the find_by_sql you mark their lace with a ? and then list the variables in order at the end.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying in your comment. Do you just wan the ID of the item returned by the query?